# User-defined Literal Operator on Macros

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

How does one use a user-defined literal operator on a macro that expands to some literal expression?

e.g.:

```
std::string operator""_str(const char* sz, std::size_t len)
{
    return std::string(sz);
}
```

Where implementation is something like:

```
#define expr "expression"
auto str = expr _str;
```

Comment: @nowi Igor is not using the same syntax at the call site as you are using in the question. I was asking, because I didn't think that a function-call-like syntax would be acceptable. If you already have to write something like `CONCAT(expr, _str);` then you can just as well use a function call directly to the operator. That would be easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need another macro that performs token pasting:

```
#define CONCAT2(A, B) A##B
#define CONCAT(A, B) CONCAT2(A, B)
auto str = CONCAT(expr, _str);
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/VIYNUE32593)

Answer (score 10):

Adjacent string literals are automatically concatenated ([[lex.ext]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext#8.sentence-1)), so

```
auto str = expr ""_str;
```

would work.

Comment: Works because this concatenation happens in translation phase 6, and macro's are fully expanded in phase 4.

Comment: @MSalters  Is that true for all compilers?

Comment: @Spencer: it's a requirement in the ISO Standard, been there for ages, and fairly easy to get right. It's true for all compilers I know, and likely for the others as well.

Comment: @MSalters Then, cpplearner's answer would be improved by adding your first comment with "by design" inserted somewhere.